# Getting a RecursionError while trying to write a recursive function to iterate over a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I'm trying to iterate over a nested dictionary by using a recursive function, however I end up getting a message which says

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

```
def iterate_over(var):
   if(len(var)>1):
      iterate_over(var)
   else:
      return var

temp={'A':[{'B':[{'D':23},{'E':43}]},{'C':44}]}
iterate_over(temp['A'])
```

Comment: In general: if there is something to iterate, then iterate, do not recurse. Python especially is great in iterations and not so great in recursions.

Answer (score 0):

In any language this form of recursion will lead to respective recursion error, as you are not changing what is passed to next recursive call. Whatever is passed to the first level (here `var`) of recursion, the same value is passed to the second level of recursion, and so on.

Further, the `temp['A']` is basically a list not a dictionary.

Try this:

```
def iterate_over(var):
    if type(var) is list :
        for x in var:
            iterate_over(x)
    elif(type(var) is dict and len(var)>0):
        print (next(iter(var.values())))
        iterate_over(next(iter(var.values())))


temp={'A':[{'B':[{'D':23},{'E':43}]},{'C':44}]}
iterate_over(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a RecursionError because the condition `len(var) > 1` will always evaluate to true since you're not updating `var` inside the function.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but your function should look something like this:

```
def iterate_over(var):
   if(len(var) > 1):
      return iterate_over(var[1:])
   else:
      return var
```